# Question about Hamilton's Quaternion Paper

Tags: quaternions

So I was reading Hamilton's paper on quaternions. http://www.emis.de/classics/Hamilton/OnQuat.pdf. On page 2, I'm having trouble following how QQ' and equations A,B,C lead to equation D. My main question is in the original expression for QQ', we have terms like iwx' and jyw'. Basically, I don't see how those i's and j's disappeared in equation D, and why logically we arrange all the terms like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't disappear; what you see is components of the new quaternion 
$$
Q''=w''+ix''+iy''+iz''=QQ'
$$

Comment: What's the logic for the grouping then in equation D?

Comment: @GabrielKho What is then the logic for the grouping of real parts and imaginary parts when you multiply two complex numbers?

Comment: Well, I mean take x'' for example, the last two terms are yz' and zy'. I don't see how those got assigned there.

Comment: @GabrielKho $jk=-kj=i$.